# Does this integrating factor look right?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given

$dy/dx-y-e^{3x}=0$

I moved $e^{3x}$ to the right side getting:

$dy/dx-y=e^{3x}$

I then figured the integrating factor would be:

$u(x)=e^{\int-1 dx}$

Therefore $u(x)= e^{-x}$

Comment: but it is not finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are on a right track. Indeed $$\mu(x)=e^{\int -1dx}=e^{-x}$$ and after multiplying the ODE by $\mu(x)$ we get: $$d\left(ye^{-x}\right)=e^{3x}\times e^{-x}$$ so $$y=e^{x}\left(\int e^{2x}dx\right)=e^x(0.5e^{2x}+C)$$

Comment: Ok!  After working on it some more, I came up with 

$y=1/2e^{x+2}x^2+Ce^{x}$

Is that correct?

Comment: @westhe32nd: I edited the post. However, you could check the point with Sami's post. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The solution $y_h$ of the homogeneous equation
$$y'-y=0$$
is
$$y_h=\lambda e^x$$
and a particular solution has the form $y_p=ae^{3x}$ so 
$$y'_p-y_p-e^{3x}=0\iff2a=1\iff a=\frac 1 2$$
hence the general solution is
$$y_g=y_h+y_p=\lambda e^x+\frac 1 2 e^{3x}$$

Comment: Completing post. :+)